# How to connect client server system with SQlite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, client-server

In client server program I want the message received from client save in "SQLite" database.I mean as code below shows "IPAddress, message and date" from server save in database.How should i connect these together? Thanks in advance.

```
    QString IPAddress= m_client->peerAddress().toString();

    qDebug()<<"IP Address:"<< IPAddress;
}

void myserver::readSocket()
{
   QByteArray message = m_client->readAll();

   qDebug() <<" Data in: " << message;

   QDate date=QDate::currentDate() ;

   qDebug() << date;

   m_client->write(message);
  }
```

---

```
 void MainWindow::createdata()
 {
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("DROP TABLE messages");
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE messages("
               "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
               "IPAddress VARCHAR(20),"
               "date VARCHAR(10),"
               "message VARCHAR(30))");


    query.prepare("INSERT INTO messages(IPAddress, date, message) values(?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Set the parameter values, and execute the query. What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: @CL.: i want automatically when the server received message it add to DB..

Comment: @Honey Call the createdata() function in your readSocket() function ?

Comment: @nos: i did it but still in query : query.addBindValue(IPAddress); it had an error IPAddress not declared in this scope.

Comment: @Honey Well, do you have a variable named IPAddress that you can access from the createdata() function ?

Comment: @nos: no just i want IPAddress from here pass to createdata();
    QString IPAddress= m_client->peerAddress().toString();

    qDebug()<<"IP Address:"<< IPAddress;
}

Comment: @Honey Then store it in a member variable of your myserver class

Comment: @nos: how should i do it?

Comment: @Honey: Are you trying to save it in databases located on server side, or client side?

Comment: @Googie: server side

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong from the begining. You put SQL related code into your client. That's wrong. You should send IPAddress (and whatever else you need) through socket into server, then server should use QSql* classes, not the client. Client sends data to server, server saves it to database.

Comment: @Googie: they are all in server class...server how should save in DB?

Comment: Is `MainWindow` class part of server or client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99829/discussion-between-googie-and-honey).